# how to paste text in input field from clipboard using python

Tags: python

i want to paste text in text input field, which is copied from pdf file. i can't use ctrl+v to paste. so is there any way to do so with python or any other?

```
from tkinter import Tk
root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
result = root.clipboard_get()
print(result)
```

this is the code that fetch data from clipboard. it prints the copied text. but when i run the script with shortcut key it does not paste the text to input field.

i also tried

```
import pyautogui
x, y = pyautogui.position()
pyautogui.click(x, y)
```

to get focus back where i want to paste text.

Comment: this is a link to the module that pastes and copies from the clipboard https://pyperclip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this after pyautogui.click(x, y)

```
pyautogui.typewrite(result)
```

so full code will be as follows

```
import pyautogui
from tkinter import Tk
root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
result = root.clipboard_get()

x, y = pyautogui.position()
pyautogui.click(x, y)
pyautogui.typewrite(result)
```

Comment: i found this after posting question. anyways thanks for the answer.

Comment: This doesn't paste the results thou, this types it.  @romaltandel

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyperclip
result = pyperclip.paste()
```

Comment: Hey there! While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: This doesn't paste into the active field, it retrieves what's on the clipboard, and puts it into a string

Answer (score 0):

You can also use pyautogui itself to do this, which pastes whatever amount of text is on the clipboard (can be large, and is done quickly) [Snagged from here](https://copyprogramming.com/howto/how-to-paste-text-in-input-field-from-clipboard-using-python)

```
import pyautogui
```

**on mac:**

```
pyautogui.hotkey('command', 'v')
```

**on windows:**

```
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')
```